# How do I combine the results (predictions) if I have generated predictions from say, randomforest, gbm, svm, nnet to get more accurate predictions?

Tags: svm, linear-regression, glm, random-forest, nnet

More specifically, how to improve my predictions by creating an ensemble? I mean I know that we perform regression on the results(predictions) one gets from different algorithms(random forest, nnet, gbm, svm). But how do we do this ?

Answer (score 1):

There exists a lot of different ways you can do to address this. One way would be to train a new top level model, which input would be a vector of the output from all other techniques.

Another way to solve this is by using the approach often used with support vector machines to solve the multiclass problem.

This approach resembles a tournament match between each model, where all the outputs are compared between them to choose a winner. Commonly this is done using one of two strategies “One Against One” or “One Against All” ( Here is a paper comparing them http://www.researchgate.net/publication/228643199_One_Against_One_or_One_Against_All_Which_One_is_Better_for_Handwriting_Recognition_with_SVMs )

These are the ways I have on top of my mind, but I am pretty sure you can find a lot of novel ways to address this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will go through the paper.